# springboot api's not working ..neither it showing any error in eclipse's console

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

[image]here is my UserController class

```
package ritu.login;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Configuration  
@RequestMapping("/vs1")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    private User getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        return userService.getUserById(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/user/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        userService.delete(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public long saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.saveOrUpdate(user);
        return user.getId();
    }

    @PutMapping("/users")
    public User Update(@RequestBody User users) {
        userService.saveOrUpdate(users);
        return users;
    }
}
```

Here is UserService class

```
package ritu.login;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        userRepository.findAll().forEach(user1 -> users.add(user1));
        return users;
    }

    public User getUserById(long id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(User users) {
        userRepository.save(users);
    }

    public void delete(long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public void update(User users, long id) {
        userRepository.save(users);
    }
}
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ritu.login</groupId>
    <artifactId>login-register</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>login-register</name>
    <description>login example</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

here is my url in postman

```
http://localhost:8080/vs1/users
```

It gives error of 404 Not found..what should i do?
here is Pojo class

```
package ritu.login;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Entity
@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")
@SessionScoped
@Component  
public class User implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7250065889869767422L;

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String validate(Long id,String name) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/any", "root", "jaygurudev1@");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Select id,name from user where id=? and name=?");
            ps.setLong(1, id);
            ps.setString(2, name);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                return "hello.xhtml";
            } else {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                        "Incorrect Username and Passowrd", "Please enter correct username and Password"));
                return  "index";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("in exception");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

i saw some tutorial on javatpoint and other website but still the issue can't get solved.
what am i missing in the code or any version related issues?
**IT GIVES 404 ERROR,WHILE HITTING URL**

Comment: Are you store data in database?

Comment: And check in postman you select GET url? Show me your `application.properties`

Comment: Also check if your server port is 8080. (On spring-boot logs for example or application.yml)

Comment: yes i have stored in database,here is my application.properties  
                     spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/any
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=jaygurudev1@
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true  @FaeemazazBhanej

Comment: @RequestMapping("/hello")
 public String sayhii() {
  return "hii";
 }
this simple is not even working @FaeemazazBhanej

Comment: C:\Users\JAY GURUDEV\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-annotations-api\9.0.56\tomcat-annotations-api-9.0.56.jar is not on its project's build path@FaeemazazBhanej

Comment: Remove tomcat dependency, spring boot provide tomcat server by default

Comment: i have removed tomcat dependency,i have added tomcat.api jar in my classpath and after that it gives 401 forbidden error in postman ,so i have removed spring security...now ,it works perfect...thanks@FaeemazazBhanej

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71176805/in-xhtml-page-jsf-attribute-are-not-rendering @FaeemazazBhanej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since,eclipse is showing error i have to add  annotation.api jar in build path after that i have **removed spring security dependency** from pom.xml and it totally works